# Button is Jumping on top on Click

Tags: jquery, css

I am using wordpress responsive theme and woocommerce plugin for my shopping cart, On my product page whenever I click the Buy Now Button it jumps on top. Product Page Link:

https://secure.presslock.org/product/pl-single/

I check the jquery codes and there is no code that can cause the button to jump on top,

In order for the user to proceed the user must hold the click button and follow the button and top and release.

Comment: I tried to inspect your page's code, but I can't find anything. Is this possibly a certain browser only issue?

Comment: i can't find also what its cause. T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen your code the problem is here in woocommerce.css

```
.woocommerce a.button:active, .woocommerce-page a.button:active, 
.woocommerce button.button:active, .woocommerce-page button.button:active, 
.woocommerce input.button:active, .woocommerce-page input.button:active, 
.woocommerce #respond input#submit:active, 
.woocommerce-page #respond input#submit:active, 
.woocommerce #content input.button:active, 
.woocommerce-page #content input.button:active{top:1px}
```

go there and remove button.button:active